# How to filter out "Nothing" values from Elm Array?

Tags: elm, option-type

I'd like to define the following function:

```
compactAndConvertToList : Array (Maybe String) -> List String
```

This function should remove all `Nothing` appearances in the given array, and convert it to `List`.

I came up with the solution below, but it feels dirty a bit.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Array

model : Array.Array (Maybe String)
model = Array.fromList [ Just "Hello", Just "Stack", Nothing, Just "Overflow" ]


compactAndConvertToList : Array.Array (Maybe String) -> List String
compactAndConvertToList maybeStrings =
  maybeStrings
    |> Array.filter (\x -> x /= Nothing)
    |> Array.map (Maybe.withDefault "")
    |> Array.toList


main = 
  model
    |> compactAndConvertToList
    |> show
```

Comment: why are there () around Maybe string?  I'm new to elm.  Why (Maybe String) and what does that do to Array.Array?

Comment: @PositiveGuy Without parenthesis around `Maybe String`, it would be interpreted as two separate arguments for `Array`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your final result is a list, you are probably better to just convert your array to a list, and then operate on it.

```
import Array 

compactAndConvertToList : Array.Array (Maybe String) -> List String
compactAndConvertToList = Array.toList >> List.filterMap identity
```

If you're not comfortable with higher-order functions, you could write it like this:

```
compactAndConvertToList arr = List.filterMap identity (Array.toList arr)
```

We take our array, apply toList to it, then apply filterMap with it. Filter map takes a function which produces a maybe, and applies it to every element in the list, discarding the `Nothing` cases. We just apply the identity functions, which discards the `Nothing` values that are already there.

In general, Arrays are good for fast random access, but if you're traversing the entire collection a bunch of times, Lists will tend to be faster. But, always start by doing it the clear way, then optimize if you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like the first version with `>>`. Somewhat unrelated questions regarding `Array` vs `List`: To build a model representing a 2 dimensional array (for [this game](http://fgcos.com/puzzle/barley-break), for example), is it better to use `Array` of `Array`s? I couldn't find how to get an item at a specific index in a `List`.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely don't want lists for that, looking up a specific element is very slow. Array of Arrays is your best bet.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this is a better answer as in 2018. Use an [elm-community/maybe-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/latest) package.

Example:

```
Maybe.Extra.values [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
```

Returns:

```
[1,3]
```